# Oracle procedure with multiple variable table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm learning a little about pl/sql and as I was working on a procedure I thought if it was possible to do something like this:

```
create or replace procedure lCProcedure(c_tables in varchar, cl_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
is
begin
    open cl_cursor for
        select * from c_tables;
end lCProcedure;
```

Where I would then do something like this:

ex:
lCProcedure(clients, cur);
lCProcedure(storage, cur);
...

each giving all the informationn about the table I requested. Is it possible?

Comment: your procedure has two parameters. In your call `lCProcedure(clients); lCProcedure(storage);` you are passing only one!

Comment: its just an example, I am currently doing this in C#, my problem is: can I use a variable to substitute the "table" I want to query in order to use the same procedure for diferent tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you?  You could

```
create or replace procedure lCProcedure(
  c_table in varchar2, 
  cl_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
is
begin
    -- Don't do this!!
    open cl_cursor for
        'select * from ' || c_tables;
end lCProcedure;
```

Should you?  Almost certainly not.  Dynamic SQL is a very powerful tool but it is relatively easy to abuse.  Having a single stored procedure that can query any table makes it impossible to use manage security via normal grants.  It eliminates the benefits of providing a defined API to applications that can remain consistent when the data model evolves.  By the same token, it eliminates the encapsulation benefits that a procedural API should provide by forcing the caller to know all the tables in the underlying data model.  And if you build a naive implementation like I did here, you're subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know I shouldn't do this but it's just to satisfy my curiosity. I waswondering about this because of the n proceduresI would need to create just to do theexact same thing and I thought that it wasa huge waste of resource when I can do it all in one. Again thank you very much.